# Spring Boot 2.7.0-SNAPSHOT giving java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.shared.artifact.filter.collection.ArtifactsFilter

Tags: spring-boot, maven, snapshot

I am getting the below error while running the Spring Boot 2.7.0-SNAPSHOT using terminal

`mvn spring-boot:run`

This command leads to below error

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/maven/shared/artifact/filter/collection/ArtifactsFilter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0 (Native Method)
```

What needs to be done in this case?

Comment: First why are you using a [SNAPSHOT version and not a milestone version](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/24/spring-boot-2-7-0-m2-available-now) furthermore this looks like an network issue based on the missing class which is part of a maven plugin... without the whole log output etc. is impossible to help...

Comment: We've seen this in the past when Spring Boot's Maven Plugin's pom file was corrupted so none of its dependencies were available. If that's happened here, you should have seen a warning about the missing or corrupted pom earlier in Maven's output.